# Please verify my induction proof: $3$| $(5 \cdot 10^{n+1} + 3\cdot 10^n + 4)$ for $n ∈ \mathbb N $

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

This is one of my exam questions and I just want to make sure I proved it right. The proof follows:

> Let $P(n)$ be the statement $(5 * $ 10<sup>n+1</sup>$ + 3*10^n + 4)$
>   **Base case:** For $n = 1, P(1) = 534$ which is divisible by 3. $✓$
>   **Induction hypothesis:** Assume that $P(k)$ is true for some $k ∈ N$.
>             This means that $(5 * $ 10<sup>k+1</sup>$ + 3*10^k + 4)$ is true and let $P(n) = 3p, p ∈ N $
>   **Induction step:** Show that $P(k+1)$ is true.
>   $(5 * $ 10<sup>k+2</sup>$ + $ 3*10<sup>k+1</sup>$ + 4)$
>   $= $$(5 * $ 10<sup>k+1</sup>$*10 + $ 3*10<sup>k</sup>$*10 + 4 + 40 - 40)$
>   $= $$(5 * $ 10<sup>k+1</sup>$*10 + $ 3*10<sup>k</sup>$*10 + 40 - 36)$
>   $= $$10(5 * $ 10<sup>k+1</sup>$ + $ 3*10<sup>k</sup>$ + 4) - 36$
>   $= $$10*3p - 36$ (induction hypothesis)
>   $= $$30*p - 36$
>   ∵ both are divisible by 3, the expression is divisible by 3.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To me it is correct.

Comment: I agree that your proof is correct.

Comment: The proof is correct, the notation is not. If $P(n)$ is a statement, then it is not also a numerical function of $n$. Use a different notation for the expression depending on $n$. Otherwise all looks good!

Comment: As an aside, a simpler shorter proof relies on modular arithmetic.  Since $10\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $5\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ one has $5\cdot 10^{n+1}+3\cdot 10^n+4\equiv -1\cdot 1^{n+1}+0\cdot 1^n+1\equiv -1+1\equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Comment: Do not edit out your answer just to hide the fact that you posted here.  If you think that someone is going to come around and see your post here and realize it is the exact same as a homework/test submission and that will cause a problem for you, then you must be doing something that you shouldn't be doing in the first place.  The purpose of this site is to act as a wealth of knowledge for all people, future users included.  By hiding what you have written, that hinders that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the criteria of divisibility by 3.
If $n=\overline{a_k\cdots a_1a_0}$ is an integer then $n$ is a multiple of $3$ iff $\sum_{i =0}^ka_i$ is a multiple of $3$.

Then $5\cdot 10^{n+1}+3\cdot10^n+4$. Clearly the decimal representation of the number give us that $5+4+3=12$ and then the number is multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, prove something stronger by induction:

> If $n\ge 1$, then $a_n = 3q_n$, where $a_n= 5 \cdot 10^{n+1} + 3\cdot 10^n + 4 = 530\cdots04$, with $n-1$ zeros, and $q_n=176\cdots68$, with $n-1$ $6$s.

This follows by induction since $a_{n+1}=10(a_n-4)+4$ and $q_{n+1}=10(q_n-8)+68$:
$$
3q_{n+1}=3(10q_n-12)=10(3q_n)-36=10a_n-36=a_{n+1}
$$